# Is it possible to create a full width row in WordPress's editor window?

Tags: css, theme-customizer

Is it possible to create a section that is full width using only WordPress's editor, including the CSS editor? (not including using a 3rd-party plugin)?

Edit: The info below was intended to demonstrate that I've done my research. I know one can edit PHP or CSS files to achieve the desired result, I am interested in working within the native parameters of WordPress.

Using the web inspector in Chrome, I can see that any content I put in the editor window belongs to `div class="entry-content"`,  but I want to place a one-line (text) banner on the front page that spans the entire screen--wider than the `entry-content` area, which means overriding the `div class="entry-content"` settings.

Here are some of the things I've tried:

- Add a unique `div` class ("banner") in the backend ("Text") editor and then add `.banner: 100%` in WordPress's CSS customizer; 
  I
- In the Customizer, added:
  `.banner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  }`
- Tried to modify `header.php` with `.banner: full-width;`

Is it possible at all to create content not constrained by the CSS specifications for the body of text a user can input using WordPress's editor (in my case, the class is `entry-content`)?

Currently, I am experimenting in WordPress theme TwentySixteen.

Comment: Yes with the right CSS, but that's a CSS question not a WP question, that can be answered using pure CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing that is to do a little bit of clever CSS hacking ;)

Here's the solution by Sven Wolfermann ([codepen](https://codepen.io/maddesigns/pen/rOMgpQ))

```
.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```